# Race condition between two async $.ajax call: Chrome is unaffected?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I've an interesting race condition with the following code with Internet Explorer 7-11 only, not with Chrome 38.

**I already fixed the problem itself**, but I would like to understand more about different browsers behaviour.

This is the event handler:

```
$("#myitem").change( function(){

    /* do stuff */

    data_select_form(111);
    data_select_form(222);

   /* do stuff */
});
```

This is the called function:

```
function data_select_form(id) {

     /* do stuff */

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/",
    data: "p=" + id,
    success: function() {

        if(id==111)
        {
            $('#aPageElement').text("You should see this until the second call completes");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#aPageElement').text("Second call complete");
        }

    }
});
}
```

The race condition happens **when my /ajax/ page returns data for the SECOND call BEFORE returning for the first one** (being async, the first one won't block the second).

The code itself it's easy to fix (just call the second on the first's $.ajax().done()), but what is really puzzling me is that different browser behave differently on the original code. **Internet Explorer respect the async aspect** and, when the first call is slow, messes up the result. **Chrome just waits for the first call to complete** nevertheless, and this is driving me nut!

Update: Firefox 33 behaves like Internet Explorer (it, too, doesn't wait for the first call to complete).

Why is Chrome behaving like this? is this a Blink bug I should report? Isn't this something that can create problems in other situations (for example, if the function is expected to do work in a parallel fashion on different object)?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say that the Chrome behaviour is entirely correct and it's IE that potentially has the issue. The call is asynchronous by nature. You are never guaranteed that the first call made will be the first to get a response.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan liked the last line in the comment.

Comment: You have it backwards! As I clearly stated, IE respects the async, Chrome always waits.

Answer (score 0):

The calls are async, so you cannot be guaranteed what order they will return in.  Different browsers use this to optimize in different ways.

For example Firefox allows you to change pref (`network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server`) in `about:config` that will limit 1 connection per domain for instance, which would ensure the order that you describe for instance, by default it is 6.

Now let's say that you have 4 large images on your html page that runs the javascript code in your example, the first connection would be used by the html document, 4 more would be used by images, that's 5 so 1 connection would be left over for your javascript, which would result in the order that you describe, if you removed 1 image from the document the result would be different however.

Anyhow to summarize you cannot rely on the response order of async requests.